# How to extract different user information into same category in a column for visualization?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataset of one million data. There is a column name 'Message' which contains all of the information about the user e.g. user email address, different category types, account type, aplication type information. Other than it is also contains null values.

Now I would like to change the entire column(A) information like this  column(B).

I have tried to use regular expression findall, findmatch but could not success.

|Column A                                       | Column B|

|config message.User@email.com/category1        |Catg 1|

|config message.User@email.com/category2        | Catg 2|

|config message.User@email.com/category1        | Catg 1|

|%null values                                   | Null|

|config message.User@email.com/category3        | Catg 3|

Comment: It would be good if you write what your current approach is. But is seems the messages are strings, so the first thing you wanna do is split each message (seems like "/" would be the separator string) and use that in order to set the value in column B

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Unless you edit this and write a proper question, it will most likely get closed.

Comment: I have updated the question. When I tried to add table, it was showing therer was error. I have added the explaination. I tried to use `.findmatch` . but no success,